# Do while loop changing variables in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

I've been trying to make a choose your adventure type of program, but I've run into a problem.  I have the whole thing running in a do while loop, and each option is an element in an array is an element. I also have if statements in the do while that can change some elements depending on what the user has already done. Here's an example of what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input;
        input=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean run;
        boolean theBoo = false;
        run = true;
        int choice;
        choice = 0;

        do {
            String[] theArray;
            theArray = new String[2];
            theArray[0] = "Hello";

            if(theBoo){
                theArray[1] = "Goodbye";
            }
            else{
                theArray[1] = "Hi";
                theBoo = true;
            }
            System.out.println(theArray[choice]);
            choice = input.nextInt();

        } while(run);
    }
}
```

For some reason though, it prints out "Goodbye" if you input 1, even though it should print "Hi", as theBoo is false. My question is: why is the do while loop changing the value of my variable, and how do I prevent it from doing so? Thanks!

Edit: Btw, I am new here, so my apologies if I did something wrong.

Edit2: First of all, thanks everyone for the quick answers. I made the changes you recommended, but its still doing the same thing. I updated the code to what it is with the changes.

Comment: Use `==` for comparisons.

Comment: What @ZouZou says is not a hint, it's the root cause of your problem!

Comment: You could use IDE for code formatting, it's very hard to read the original post. Many errors come from low code readability.

Comment: Why do people insist on using `if(boolean == true)`. It is fairly obvious that the `if` statement evaluates a `boolean` so it should be obvious that `if(boolean)` is the correct construction. This also has be nice feature of preventing the `if(boolean = true)` which is what we have here.

Comment: This time I formatted source code for you, but don't count on that. People here are not likely to waste even 10 seconds trying to make sense out of a mess of curly braces wildly laid around. Please be kind towards other people and always provide clean, nicely formatted code.

Answer (score 2):

update your code to

```
if(theBoo){
    theArray[1] = "Goodbye";
}
else{
    theArray[1] = "Hi";
    theBoo = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` and not `=` to test for equality. In fact, for Booleans you don't need any explicit equality signs. You can just have:

```
if(theBoo)
      //something
else
      //something else
```

Notice how you don't have two `if`s. Not only is it unnecessary, but it doesn't make logical sense to test `(theBoo==true)` and then `if(theBoo==false)` (where, again, you can completely omit the `==true` or `==false` parts). If the first condition is true, the second can't (as it's the opposite of the first), so you really want an `else` or `else if` there.

Same with the `==` for the while condition at the bottom. You can just have:

```
while(run)
```

Another comment - you often don't have any need to define the variable on a separate line from the declaration. You can just have:

```
boolean theBoo = false;
```

instead of:

```
boolean theBoo;
theBoo = false;
```

It's shorter and cleaner the first way, on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Your using one = sign, you're setting the value of theBoo to true, not testing its value

Use == for tests

fixed code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input;
    input=new Scanner(System.in);
boolean run;
boolean theBoo;
theBoo = false;
run = true;
int choice;
choice = 0;

do{
String[] theArray;
theArray = new String[2];
theArray[0] = "Hello";

if(theBoo == true){
    theArray[1] = "Goodbye";
}
if(theBoo == false){
    theArray[1] = "Hi";
    theBoo = true;
}
System.out.println(theArray[choice]);
choice = input.nextInt();

}while(run == true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases in Java where the static typing doesn't prevent a silly mistake.

The expression *`x = v` is always an assignment* and the result has the same type as that of the `v` expression. Unfortunately, in this case it means that the `boolean`-typed result doesn't throw a type error when used with the conditional ..

```
boolean a = true;
// a -> true
boolean b = a = false;  // boolean b = (a = false);
// a -> false
// b -> false
```